# How to fix line spacing in Gmail signature?

Tags: gmail, email-signature

I use Gmail and someone sent me an email with a signature that I quite liked the style of and I thought I could reuse it myself. I copied the signature into my Gmail settings signature box and changed the text to reflect my details. But when I saved my Gmail settings, for some reason the spacing between text lines all increased so it looks wrong - lines are spaced too far apart - and I don't know how to fix the line spacing as I don't see any tool for spacing in the Gmail signature editor.

How can I fix the line spacing? Or how do I go about editing the underlying HTML source to fix the line spacing? Sorry, I am unclear how to do that or how to access the HTML source.

Answer (score 6):

Make Your cursor placed at the end of first line and press **DELETE** button until the second line is just beside the first line.Then after press **SHIFT+ENTER**.

Do the Same for all the lines....

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by pasting the text into Microsoft Word, then using word's Format > Paragraph feature to remove any line spacing. Then copy/paste the fixed text back to Gmail settings signature box. Seems to be fine now.

Maybe same will work with any document editor, I'm not sure, but Word was what I had to hand.

Answer (score 1):

I highlighted the text after paseting into the signature and double click the capital underlined T with the small x. Remove formatting Control-\
Then deleted the unwanted lines